# Two divs in a column, both with dynamic widths. Can I force the bottom div to have the same width as the above one?

Tags: css, html, width

Consider the following markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top">
        <img />
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
        Some text, there we go.
    </div>
</div>
```

`<img>` has fixed height. Width of `top` and `bottom` is dynamic. `top`'s content may be wider than `bottom`'s content and vice versa. I need to make it so that `bottom`'s width is equal to `top`'s width at all times.

Can this be done with pure CSS? Or is JS neccessary?

Comment: I have a fiddle going for it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3YtyB/. Haven't found something that works yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this via pure CSS ([courtesy of Artem Polikarpov](http://artgorbunov.ru/bb/soviet/20120503/) (in Russian))

```
<style>
  .ap-pic {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1px;
  }

  .ap-pic .caption {
    display: block;
  }
</style>

<div class="ap-pic">
  <img src="pic.jpg">
  <span class="caption">long text that has to go on the next line blah blah blah</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The #top and #bottom elements are'nt really related in any way, other than having a common parent, so me thinks you're going to have some trouble setting the width of one element to be exactly the same as the other element unless you place one element inside the other etc.

A quick jQuery fix would be :

```
$("#bottom").css('width', $("#top").width());
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/HgGjW/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have been fighting with this solution for a couple weeks and fine tuning it for the better part of four months. Essentially I use JQuery to stay on top of it and make sure that no matter what two elements are the same width.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PseudoNinja/f4kz81tm/)

```
/**
 * Determine basic dimensions of an element
 *  @author PseudoNinja (email at pseudoninja dot com)
 * @returns object
 */

jQuery.fn.getDimensions = function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        dimensions = {
            width: 0,
            paddingLeft: 0,
            paddingRight: 0,
            borderLeft: 0,
            borderRight: 0,
            getOuterWidth: function () {
                return parseInt(this.width) + parseInt(this.paddingLeft) + parseInt(this.paddingRight) + parseInt(this.borderLeft) + parseInt(this.borderRight);
            }
        };

    dimensions.width = $this.width();
    dimensions.paddingLeft = $this.css('padding-left').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
    dimensions.paddingRight = $this.css('padding-right').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
    dimensions.borderLeft = $this.css('border-left-width').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
    dimensions.borderRight = $this.css('border-right-width').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, '');
    dimensions.outerWidth = $this.outerWidth();

    return dimensions;
};

/** size element to width if target
 *  @author PseudoNinja (email at pseudoninja dot com)
 *  @param  {string} target - selector of element to clone width
 */
jQuery.fn.sizeTo = function (target) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $target = $(target),
        myDimensions = $this.getDimensions(),
        targetDimensions = $target.getDimensions(),
        difference = targetDimensions.outerWidth - myDimensions.outerWidth,
        adjOuterWidth = 0
    ;

    if (difference > 0) {
        myDimensions.width = myDimensions.width + difference;
        adjOuterWidth = myDimensions.getOuterWidth();
        $this.width(myDimensions.width);
    }

    // Add persistance to size change
    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.sizeTo(target);
    }, 100);

    return $this;
};

// USAGE EXAMPLE
//    $(function(){
//        $("#div1").sizeTo($("#div2"));
//    });
```

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to do it with pure CSS. Set both element's width as 100%.

Answer (score -1):

If your doing it that way, then I wouldn't use div's, I would use a list.